# OSPF - networks/links don't get advertised

Tags: ipv4, ospf, ipv6, network

In my Multiarea-OSPF configuration I can ping my neighbor, but nobody which is more than one hop away (for instance ABR2).
Also traceroute just shows "1 * * *   -     2 * * *    -    3 * * *"

Can anybody think of possible mistakes in the OSPF configuration?

[image]

configuration:

```
en
 conf t
 no ip domain-lookup
 ipv6 unicast-routing

 int loopback 0
  ip address 2.2.2.2 255.255.255.0
  exit

 ipv6 router ospf 1
  area 45 range 2001:db8:18:4500::/56
  auto-cost reference-bandwidth 100000
  router-id 2.2.2.2
  exit
 router ospf 1
  area 45 range 10.45.0.0 255.255.0.0
  area 0 range 10.0.0.0 255.255.0.0
  auto-cost reference-bandwidth 100000
  network 10.45.0.0 255.255.255.252 area 45
  network 10.45.0.4 255.255.255.252 area 45
  network 10.0.0.0 255.255.255.252 area 0
  network 10.0.0.4 255.255.255.252 area 0

 int s0/1/0
  ip add 10.45.0.1 255.255.255.252
  ipv6 add 2001:db8:18:4501::1/64
  ipv6 ospf 1 area 45
  ip ospf hello-interval 3
  ipv6 ospf hello-interval 3
  no sh

 int s0/1/1
  ip add 10.45.0.5 255.255.255.252
  ipv6 add 2001:db8:18:4502::1/64
  ipv6 ospf 1 area 45
  ip ospf hello-interval 3
  ipv6 ospf hello-interval 3
  no sh

 int s0/0/0
  ip add 10.0.0.2 255.255.255.252
  ipv6 add 2001:db8:18:0001::2/64
  ipv6 ospf 1 area 0
  ip ospf hello-interval 3
  ipv6 ospf hello-interval 3
  no sh

 int s0/0/1
  ip add 10.0.0.6 255.255.255.252
  ipv6 add 2001:db8:18:0002::2/64
  ipv6 ospf 1 area 0
  ip ospf hello-interval 3
  ipv6 ospf hello-interval 3
  no sh
```

Comment: Why did you delete the configuration?

Comment: because it's hard to see what someone's got wrong just by looking at one configuration and not knowing the network-topology/ip-scheme. Or should I put the config back again in the question?

Comment: Even better, put the configuration back and add a simpel topology drawing. :-)

Comment: Nice! one up vote for you. :-)

Comment: Network command in ospf uses wildcard bits. Use 0.0.0.3 instead of 255.255.255.252 etc. Or simply use `ip ospf 1 area 0` though I'm not sure this is supported in PT's image.

Comment: @ar_ Do you know why some commands use wildcard and some not?

Comment: @watchme I suppose this is related to implementation in the sw/hw. Some operations are just more simple when using wildcard.

Comment: What is the output of show ip ospf neighbors? Are the neighbor relationships established? Share the outputs please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @ar_ pointed out in the comments of my question: The problem was, that I configured the network command in a wrong way. So I used subnetmasks instead of wildcard masks. (network-commands in OSPF need wildcard masks).

@RonMaupin added the information in the comments of this answer, that in the newest IOS-version both ways (subnetmask and wildcardmasks) work.

Comment: Although, the very latest IOS versions seem to correct that for you.

Comment: @RonMaupin Do you mean it can handle both, subnet- and wildcardmask?

Comment: Yes, but you probably should use one or the other, otherwise it could be very confusing when looking at it. I suppose it looks to see where the consecutive bit are (at the beginning or end) to determine how to interpret it.

Comment: I'm not sure at which version this was added.

Comment: @RonMaupin How can it distuingish when the subnetmask is 0.0.0.0 for instance?

Comment: I don't know the details. A mask of `0.0.0.0` would mean any address, and the OSPF equivalent wildcard mask would be `255.255.255.255`. It does work correctly with `network 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0  area <x>` or `network 0.0.0.0 255.255.255.255 area <x>`.

Comment: @RonMaupin I mean one can also interpret it as a wildcard mask of 0.0.0.0

Comment: Yes, I know what you mean, but it seems to work either way, probably because it sees the `0.0.0.0` network. The best thing to do now that IOS supports it is to forget using network statements to determine which interfaces participate, and simply place the OSPF commands directly on the interfaces. You must do that for IPv6, anyway, so you can simply do it for both IPv4 and IPv6.